Add new rows to dataset in nested for loop
The following script works when data4 is used to create dataframe, hours_date_match_barc. It breaks when I want to use data3 and I believe it is because it is not able to add more rows to out.
ValueError: Length of values () does not match length of index ()

I really need to be able to use data3 because I need my compress_and_process_group function to be able to loop over all the rows in hours_date_match_barc.
I am looking for help to edit my function to loop over each row in hours_date_match_barc and compare it to laborcompl_ref. I tried to add a index += 1 and a continue statement but that didn't work. I'm not sure where to tell my code to move on to the next index, row in hours_date_match_barc. It is also important to note that my output should at least have more rows since there is multiple instance of BARC in data4 but it doesn't do that as well.
Two part issue:

I need to be able to use df3.
If you run df4, you will see that only 11 rows are in the output. I am expecting about 152 rows ,if it truly iterated through the entire dataset. This indicates that it is only looking at the first row of hours_date_match_barc and stopping.

Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

data2={
    "ID": [ "BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR"],
    "PHASENAME": [ "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C",],
    "DAY_COUNTER": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100],
    "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT": [0.002,0.002,0.002,0.005,0.006,0.009,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.011,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.014,0.014,0.014,0.013,0.013,0.015,0.015,0.014,0.014,0.014,0.012,0.011,0.011,0.011,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.013,0.013,0.013,0.012,0.012,0.012,0.011,0.011,0.011,0.011,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.008,0.008,0.008,0.008,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.008,0.008,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.009,0.008,0.007,0.007,0.007,0.005,0.004,0.004,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.004,0.005,0.005,0.005,0.006,0.008,0.008,0.009,0.009],
    "compl_ref_index" : ["BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC",],
    }

data3={
    "ID": ["FOO","FOO","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR"],
    "PHASENAME": ["L","L","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"],
    "C_DAYS": [17,  17, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14,],
    "Multi_Factor": [5.882353,5.882353,9.090909,9.090909,9.090909,9.090909,7.692308,7.692308,7.692308,7.692308,8.333333,8.333333,8.333333,8.333333,7.142857,7.142857,7.142857],
    "compl_ref_index" : ["FOOL","FOOL","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC", "BARC",]
    }



data4={
    "ID": ["BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR"],
    "PHASENAME": ["C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"],
    "C_DAYS": [11,  11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14,],
    "Multi_Factor": [9.090909,9.090909,9.090909,9.090909,7.692308,7.692308,7.692308,7.692308,8.333333,8.333333,8.333333,8.333333,7.142857,7.142857,7.142857],
    "compl_ref_index" : ["BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC","BARC", "BARC",]
    }

laborcompl_ref=pd.DataFrame(data2)
hours_date_match_barc=pd.DataFrame(data3)


def compress_and_process_group(group):
    # check if hours_date_match["compl_ref_index"] is in row["compl_ref_index"]
    for index, row in hours_date_match_barc.iterrows():
        if row["compl_ref_index"] in group["compl_ref_index"].values:
            # perform action below
            n = hours_date_match_barc["C_DAYS"].iloc[0] 
            mf = (
                hours_date_match_barc["Multi_Factor"].mean().astype(int)
            )  
            first_day = group["DAY_COUNTER"].iloc[0]
            rep = np.tile(group.values, (n // len(group) + 1, 1))
            out = pd.DataFrame(rep, columns=group.columns).iloc[:n]
            out["DAY_COUNTER"] = range(first_day, n + first_day)
            out["C_DAYS"] = n
            labor_values = group["DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT"].values

            print(f"found id {row['compl_ref_index']}  in second dataset")
            for i in range(0, len(out)):
                sum_of_rows = np.add.reduceat(labor_values, range(0, len(labor_values), mf))
            selected_data = sum_of_rows[:n]
            out["NEW_LBR_COMPL"] = selected_data

            return out
        index += 1
    print(f"done")


# Process each group separately and concatenate the results
result = pd.concat([compress_and_process_group(group) for _, group in laborcompl_ref.groupby(["ID", "PHASENAME"])])




That code works perfectly fine for me.  What, exactly, is failing for you?

@TimRoberts Sorry, I added the np.Nan to see if I could fix my code before I posted it. I will update that line once this posts.  Once it updates, you will see "ValueError: Length of values (15) does not match length of index (17)" But if you change df3 to df4, you will get 11 rows but I am expecting about 152 lines

@TimRoberts The 11 rows shows that it is only iterating through the first row of 'hours_date_match_barc' and stopping. I need it to continue making its way through the dataset

Identify what has length 15 and what is 17.  Then reconcile the difference.

@hpaulj if it's iterating through hours_date_match_barc to add to out . Would the length (or the amount of rows) matter? Sorry, if I don't understand

@hpaulj is there a way to append out in each iteration so there will not be a index issue?

Stepping back, you (a) haven't shown us the code that fails, and (b) you haven't identified which statement gets the error.
